# How to create a Jenkins job config.xml?

Tags: jenkins

When I create a jenkins job via the API, I use a previous job's `config.xml`, make my modifications and then make the POST call to create the job.

My questions is, is there a way to generate this programmatically? I.e. is there a structure of a `config.xml`, what XML entities it should have, what values, etc so I can write a small module to generate one and send it to the jenkins API call?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any mandatory XML entities. Submitting an empty structure should result in a job that has default values for all settings.

What you want to do is exactly what's done by the [Jenkins Job Builder](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/). It provides a YAML-based framework for creating Job configuration XML files and submitting them to Jenkins. It's a common alternative to the Job DSL plugin. I wouldn't recommend to re-implement such a solution yourself -- handling all the plugin-specific XML configuration parts will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

We create our jobs using [Job DSL plugin](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/). You can try the playground http://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/.

At first, it seems that it is hard to learn, but after the first seed job, it is much better. 
When we started writing our scripts we were afraid that there will not be suitable API methods for our needs. It turned out that we had one such case, which was solved using the [configure block](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block).

Get started guide [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL).

Comment: That's what we're diong right now but for our new project I'd prefer some guide that'd help us generate a correct config.xml from code

Comment: So you don`t want use DSL? The approach with the REST API (http://localhost:8080/createItem?name=myjob) seems more error prone to me. What are the differences between your jobs? Are they too different?

Comment: They aren't too different at the moment but I'm just wondering later on if I need to create different kinds of jobs, shouldn't the config.xml generation be dynamic (: